# Why add_action works only from functions.php not plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

When I put my code to `functions.php`

starting with

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'do_something' );
here is my code
```

It Works! But when I put it in `plugin`

```
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

    if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Some_class' ) ) {

    class  WC_Some_class {
            public function __construct() {
            add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'do_something' );
}
script ...

}
}
// finally instantiate our plugin class and add it to the set of globals
        $WC_Some_class = new WC_Some_class();
    }
}
```

This does not work. Why is it?

Comment: What do you mean with "does not work"? Try doing a `print()` or something in the constructor, is the constructor called at all? Where is `do_something` defined, within the class? Have you made sure that the plugin is activated, have you flushed the cache?

Comment: Plugin is activated, and script call specifis URL everytime, when new order is completed. When this script is in `functions.php`, it is working. But when I put it in plugin (same script), it is not working, doing nothing :(

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273432/wocommerce-call-url-after-complete-order) here is long version of this code (I edited it and repaired few bugs). But in the end it is the same code where in `Functions.php` is OK, and in `plugin` is broken.

Comment: Try to debug your script, making sure that the file is loaded, that the constructor is run and so on e.g make sure that the `add_action()` call is really executed. You could also set `WP_DEBUG` to true in your wp-config.php file.

Comment: Hi @PodujatieEu - no need to mark questions as solved. They are removed from the 'open questions' list by virtue of their being ticked/accepted `:-)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of those instances where by removing bits of your code and being a little over enthusiastic with the delete key, has led to pretty important information being lost.

However i'll take a stab in the dark and presume you're moving the function from functions.php INTO the class. Therefore your add_action has to know that it needs to call the function (method) of a class, NOT a globally defined function.

Try:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', array(&$this, 'do_something') );
```

Comment: Notice that I asked about this in my previous comment=)

Comment: You are myyyyyyy GOOOOOD!!! thank you very much
I am new here so do not know how to give you bigger reputation, or whatever, but thank you so much