# How To Display Customer Order Details in Thank you page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using flatsome theme. I have installed Payumoney gateway that needs one returning page after successful payment. So I have created a thank you page. I want to know how to show customer order details and customer information on thank you page after successful payment.

Comment: SO is not a coding service. Please provide us with what you have so far, issues with your code, etc.

Comment: Use session for do that

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce has a build in page for redirecting after the order has been completed. The page contains all the order details.

Would it not be possible to link to this page?

The link looks like this:
/checkout/order-received/108/?key=wc_order_uOAK7l7LUL2m9

108 - is the order number
?key=wc_order_uOAK7l7LUL2m9 - is the order string generated by Woocommerce

You would need to get these details and insert them into the redirect link.

Maybe this will give you some guidance. [Woocommerce call url (after complete order)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273432/woocommerce-call-url-after-complete-order)